# $e^{g(z)}$ is bounded, then $g$ has to be bounded - Continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

I thought when $e^{g(z)}$ is bounded, then $g$ has to be bounded. Someone told me that it is not necessarily true because $|e^{x+iy}|=|e^{x+niy}|$ for each $n$. Is anyone could explain to me in details why we have to add the continuity as condition to be true?

Comment: Be quite careful with complex functions........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with continuity it is false.

Define $g(z) = i|z|$. This function is continuous and not bounded. However $e^{g(z)}$ is bounded.

Comment: Which conditions I could add to obtain something true?

Comment: For example holomorphy. Is $g$ is holomorphic, then by Liouville $e^{g(z)}$ must be constant and then $g$ also.

Comment: If g is holomorphic, then $e^{g(z)}$ is bound?

Comment: No but if $g$ is holomorphic, then $e^g$ is also. But, by hypothesis $e^g$ must be bounded and by Liouville a bounded holomorphic function is constant. Hence $e^g$ is constant and of course this implies $g$ is constant. Finally because $g$ is constant, it is obviously bounded.